# Collect values from multiple rows in SAS/SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I have a question on how to collect values from multiple rows for every subject-time pair? I have tried to sum up the values for the pair with sum() function, then tried to replace old variables. Since there are 300+ variables, and over 1 million records, I did not find an efficient way to do this, please help.

I attached the picture as below to illustrate what I need. (all the blanks are 0)

```
data have;
    input subject time var1-var5;
    datalines;
100 6 . . . . .
100 6 . 1 . . .
100 6 . . 1 . .
100 8 1 . . . .
100 8 . . . 1 .
100 8 . . 1 . .
100 8 . . . . 1
;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really want the SUM() (ie how many 1's there are) or the MAX (ie are there any 1's)?

Comment: I think MAX fit the purpose here.

Comment: Your image does not pass the add-blocker of many organizations. You better paste text.

Answer (score 4):

SQL will be much more difficult. If you use a data step, you can use the `update` statement trick to collapse all the rows.

```
data want;
    update have(obs=0)
           have
    ;
    by subject time;
run;
```

```
subject time    var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
100     6       .       1       1       .       .
100     8       1       .       1       1       1
```

If you have all zeros instead of missing values, you can use `proc means`:

```
proc means data=have noprint;
    by subject time;
    var var1-var5;
    output out=want(drop=_:)
        sum=;
run;
```

Or you can use its high performance variant, `proc hpsummary`:

```
proc hpsummary data=have;
    class subject time;
    var var1-var5;
    output out=want(drop=_:)
        sum=;
run;
```

```
subject time    var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
100     6       0       1       1       0       0
100     8       1       0       1       1       1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works. Do you mind to explain more about "sum()=var1-var4"? I've used sum(va1,var2) and sum (of var1-var5), but not seen your command before. Thank you.

Comment: SUM= option of the OUTPUT statement in PROC MEANS/SUMMARY is one of many statistics that the proc can calculate. It is how you tell the PROC what name(s) to use for the variable it will create to hold the value of that statistic.  It really has nothing to with the SUM() function you mentioned.

Comment: @Jingxin sorry for the confusion. Parentheses in sum= are optional in proc means/proc hpsummary. I have clarified the code.  It's a little bit of a weird syntax. Normally if you want to sum a variable, you'll say sum(var)=new_var. You can instead have it automatically use the same names as in your `var` statement by simply saying `sum=`. It is implied that the right side of `=` are the names of your variables in your `var` statement. It also accepts empty parentheses for no names, which are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

PROC SQL is probably not the right tool.  The syntax would be too cumbersome. Use PROC SUMMARY.

Assuming you want to test if ANY of the observations are 1 then use MAX statistic.  If you instead what to count the number of 1's then use the SUM statistic.

If the data is already sorted use a BY statement.

```
proc summary data=have ;
  by subject time;
  var var1 -- var5 ;
  output out=want max= ;
run;
```

If not then use a CLASS statement, make sure to include the NWAY option.

```
proc summary data=have nway ;
  class subject time;
  var var1 -- var5 ;
  output out=want max= ;
run;
```